# where better to store pictures for website

Tags: image, seo

I am planning many pictures in my site, where better to store pictures for website, in website or in photohosting, will be the images found by google-images if I store the images in photohosting?

Comment: It is not possible to answer such a vague question. Are these your own pictures? What data sizes and formats are you talking about? How many is "many"? Thousands? Millions? Are these static images, or will they change? What kind of "photohosting" are you talking about? Are you running your own servers, or are you going to pay? Or are you looking for free hosting?

Comment: I mean photohosting from where I taking image url and put it in my img src="hhttp://photohosting.com/myimage.gif", the image src will be another site, for example www.fotki.yandex.ru. I am not looking for free hosting, I pay for it, I just want to save space and traffic, I wanted to know will google be bring the images from my site if their source in another site..?

Comment: yes the pictures are mine and they are animated gifs, and about 600Kb every picture. I am planing that will be many, about 2000, I opened my site 5 days ago, and already have 150 posts and every posts contains about 7-8 animated gifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your images and their landing pages are accessible by Google's crawler, from SEO point of view it doesn't really matter where you store/host the images: Google Images will be able to associate the images with their respective landing pages regardless of their location.

However there are some gotchas that you want to pay attention to, for instance, just images on a page won't do magic, you also need some text that is related the image. You can find more tips about optimizing your images (e.g. directory structure) in the SEO Starter Guide.

[Google SEO Starter Guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)